# Unit Test watch kit extension

Tags: unit-testing, watchkit

Is there a way to write unit tests for watch kit extensions in swift 3?
So far i have done these,
1. Set the defines Module to Yes
2. Set the Enable Testability to true
3. Set the target as the test project
4. tried using the @testable import

None of these work. My interfacecontroller is nil and with the @testable import, my project does not even build.

Answer (score 3):

Although old question the answer is still valid:

There is **no** support for WatchOS regarding the XCTest suite - no UI testing and no unit testing.

I hope this answer has to be updated in the future.